# dojo timeout exceeded on xhr post

Tags: dojo, xpages

In an xpages application I get a **dojo timeout exceeded** response, if the client uses a very slow internet connection:

*Screenshots Google Developer Tools:*

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for any response :)

Comment: My advice: profile your application and make sure you don't transfer too much content in requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet allows you to extend the timeout https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=extend-partial-refresh-timeout.

Comment: In more recent versions of Domino Designer, you can also set this application-wide on Xsp Properties, on General Tab, in the Timeouts section - "Partial update timeout"